# PHP jSon data clean values for unwanted white spaces

Tags: php, json, space

Below is my JSON data which i get it by using

```
$json = json_encode($array);
```

**my JSON Data;**

```
{
"id":"352",
"date":"2013-12-25 01:10:06",
"category":"2",
"subtitle":null,
"description":" This text is description... ",
"hit":"144",
"rate":"50.00",
"active":"1"
}
```

Think that there are thousands of items like this.

But the problem is how can I trim the description value of this object automatically when running json_encode?

I dont wanna use "for each" because of performance i think.

Thanks...

Comment: Best option might be to look at the code, where you generate/retrieve that string and put an additional `trim()` in there.

Comment: Why are you worrying about the performance of a `foreach()` before you've even tested it? The bottleneck is not going to be a loop, even with a thousand items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use trim in `array_map` as :

```
$json = json_encode(array_map('trim',$array));
```

Comment: Issue with this approach is it's very inefficient